# How to run a new terminal from a python script with an argument?

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, arguments

I'd like to call a python script (processing.py) within another python script (main.py). The processing.py enters a loop (realtime-processing some audiochannels from an interface) so that the main.py can't proceed. Is there a possibility to start the processing.py in the background and the main program continues with its tasks. 
I tried to start the two files in separate terminals and it works fine, but i have to pass an argument from the main to the processing script and i don't want to enter the parameters manually in the terminal.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute terminal commands inside python code like this:

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.Popen("python C:/.../processing.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
test.communicate()
```

Then if you want them to run in parallel you can use Threading